# How to span child process with administrative privileges from parent process with administrate privileges in C#?

Tags: c#, process, console, runas, output-redirect

How to spawn child process with administrative privileges without using `verb`=`runas`?

The parent process has administrative privileges. And I would like to put output (not just plain text, but 'colored') to the console (output) of the parent process.

Comment: So, I assume that writing in colors requires administrative permissions? You could try redirecting the STDOUT of the child process to the STDIN of the parent process. Then, have the parent process decorate whatever comes in from the STDIN with colors, and send it to it's STDOUT (ie: the console window).

Or, spawn the child process within a thread of the parent process. Read the STDOUT of the child process, and Console.WriteLine() within the thread with decorations.

Comment: I do not know how to start the child process with administrative permissions.

Comment: Why does the child process need administrative permissions? From the way your question was worded it sounded like the only reason you need it executed as an administrator is to write to console in colors?

Comment: The child process is MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from Win API ([unmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301501.aspx)).
Child process will have the same privileges as parent process and will be runned in the same console window, as parent one.